# Shopify JavaScript React how to include a local file in the code?

Tags: javascript, fetch, shopify

I'm currently making an app for Shopify and I'm stuck with one problem that I can't seem to solve or find any helpful answer from Google.

I need a FrontEnd button to run a script written in JavaScript. This script is located on the server locally in a different folder.

The page is written entirely in JavaScript React and there is no HTML in there.

I tried to import this js file, but it does not allow importing due to some error. Trying to fix this error, an error occurs with the code itself and it stops working adequately. This is why I gave up trying to import the file.

Then I tried to use fetch, but I just can't achieve the result that the page would at least see my file on the server.
FrontEnd button

```
onClick = {() => {
          fetchText ()
        }}
```

At the bottom of the pages / index.js file is this function, which the button calls. The readme.txt file is located in this path: pages / readme.txt

```
async function fetchText () {
  var a = fetch ("/ readme.txt")
    .then (promiseResult => {
      console.log (promiseResult)
      return promiseResult.text ()
    })
    .then (responseResult => {console.log (responseResult)})
}
```

Everything that displays in the browser console:
**Response {type: "basic", url: "https://ooo.example.com/readme.txt", redirected: false, status: 404, ok: false,…}**

All the data about the page is also written at the bottom, but the bottom line is that no matter how I try to write the code itself, it always gives the same 404 error, that is, Not Found

Comment: Try adding the script tag in your <head> possibly ?

Comment: The page is written completely using only React and there is no <head> component like in html

Comment: The url in your Response is /readme.txt instead of /pages/readme.txt. Have you tried adding /pages to your fetch url?

Comment: Yes, I tried various paths where this file could be located, but nothing works. The /pages/readme.txt path also doesn't work. Moving this file to some other directories does not work either.